# Unusual Julia prompt in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, julia

I just updated to Julia 1.9.0 and now whenever I define something in the text editor I'm getting the prompt `#87` instead of the usual `julia>` prompt, though I can still access the usual prompt directly from the terminal.

[image]

I can define simple functions in the text editor (even though this #87 prompt shows), but can't define structs (it freezes) unless I do it directly from the terminal, but this is inconvenient. Why is this happening and please how can I solve it?

Comment: The VS Code extension wasn't fully compatible with Julia 1.9 when you posted this, the recommendation was to use the Pre-release version. But now the updated extension has been released on the stable channel as v1.47.2, and VS Code should auto-update to that version. Does the update fix the issue with the prompt?

Comment: It is fixed now. Thanks!